# designing payroll system C# SQl Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am having a little trouble in creating the payroll management system. Here are a few queries that I had with regard to the system, if you can help:

The salary for an employee is made up of various salary components. Each salary component has 3 rules associated with it, a Calculation Rule (Calculate component as % of another component, or % of a fixed number or a fixed number), an Eligibility Rule (whether an Employee/Dept is eligible for a component) and a Constraint Rule which limits tha max and min of a component. Every company should be able to define its own rules for each of the component. How can this be achieved?

These rules are editable and can be edited by a user. IN such a case, how do I retain the previous value, so that the change does not affect my past values?

How do I store the salary information of each employee for each month. I am now able to calculate a month's salary but storing it in the database with year_id, month_id, emp_id, sal_id  etc, is very tedious. is there any other way?

Comment: I don't think we can design your system for you...

Comment: I dont want the system to be designed for me. i havfe already done that. the problem is that it is static and not dynamic, as i want. that is where i am stuck

Comment: which seems to be a fundamental part of the design, no?

Comment: Why would you even want to design your own payroll system? There are hundreds of off-the-shelf solutions available for a fraction of the cost of inventing and supporting one yourself.

Comment: @sqlvogel this is a very small firm that wants the system. they want a very basic yet customized model. i suggested off the shelf, but none worked for them.

Answer (score 2):

> These rules are editable and can be edited by a user. IN such a case,
>   how do I retain the previous value, so that the change does not affect
>   my past values?

Store the values you calculate separately from the subsystem that defines and executes the calculations.

What you actually do--who you pay, how much, on what date--needs to be securely isolated from the dynamic parts of your system. (That means you need to store it in a separate table.) When it's isolated,

- it's easy to audit,
- changes to the dynamic part can't possibly affect the payroll history,
- the dynamic part can be replaced or dropped altogether without affecting payroll history.

> How do I store the salary information of each employee for each month.
>   I am now able to calculate a month's salary but storing it in the
>   database with year_id, month_id, emp_id, sal_id etc, is very tedious.
>   is there any other way?

If your head didn't explode when you typed "year_id" and "month_id", this payroll project is not a good fit for you.  Take @sqlvogel's advice, and buy an off-the-shelf system.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. as for the second part, i didn't mean year_id, month_id...what i meant was storing the data as per the year and month... sorry it was a huge typing blunder on my part.